# Cordova 3.2 ios add plugin "Which config.xml? Where is it?"

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

My app name is mobile-app

1. Create a cordova project
2. add ios platform
3. add plugin "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts"
4. go to project folder /platforms/ios/mobile-app/ and add the following to config.xml

> ```
> <feature name="Contacts">
>     <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
> </feature>
> ```

1. want to build the ios project with terminal "cordova build ios"

I get the error in terminal:

```
generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
Preparing ios project
Compiling app on platform "ios" via command "/Users/test/mobile-app/platforms/ios/cordova/build" 
[Error: An error occurred while building the ios project.** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
2014-01-13 20:49:45.743 xcodebuild[6403:4807]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/test/mobile-app/platforms/ios/build/mobile-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile-app.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVContacts.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CDVContacts.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fa634d724e0 {NSFilePath=/Users/test/mobile-app/platforms/ios/build/mobile-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile-app.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVContacts.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa634d72430 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/test/mobile-app/platforms/ios/build/mobile-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile-app.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVContacts.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa634d723f0>{name = (null), num = 8}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2014-01-13 20:49:45.774 xcodebuild[6403:5d03]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/test/mobile-app/platforms/ios/build/mobile-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile-app.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVContact.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CDVContact.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fa634e56370 {NSFilePath=/Users/test/mobile-app/platforms/ios/build/mobile-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile-app.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVContact.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa634e58160 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/test/mobile-app/platforms/ios/build/mobile-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile-app.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVContact.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa634e53090>{name = (null), num = 9}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/mobile-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile-app.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVContacts.o mobile-app/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts/CDVContacts.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/mobile-app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile-app.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVContact.o mobile-app/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts/CDVContact.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a known bug of los with cordova.

you must remove ios platform with cordova platform remove ios.

then install your plugin.

then add ios platform again.

if you don't do with this order ios seem don't be able to install the plugin right.

i hope this may help you. regards.

Comment: thank you - was pulling my hair out for a bit :) +100000