# Phonegap doesn't copy plugin files to ios platforms directory during build

Tags: ios, cordova

```
rm -rf plugins/*
rm -rf platforms/*

phonegap build ios //this works

phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git

phonegap build ios
```

Building for ios after adding a plugin fails.  Here is the error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/PondMD.build/Debug-iphoneos/PondMD.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVDevice.o PondMD/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.device/CDVDevice.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
2014-01-16 10:32:15.055 xcodebuild[69605:1007] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 37B30044-3B14-46BA-ABAA-F01000C27B63 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XCode4_beginning_of_line.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2014-01-16 10:32:16.630 xcodebuild[69605:4203]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/william/working/PhonegapPondMD/platforms/ios/build/PondMD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PondMD.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVDevice.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CDVDevice.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fe7a57a7440 {NSFilePath=/Users/william/working/PhonegapPondMD/platforms/ios/build/PondMD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PondMD.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVDevice.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe7a57aaed0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/william/working/PhonegapPondMD/platforms/ios/build/PondMD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PondMD.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVDevice.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3575/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe7a57ab420>{name = (null), num = 7}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

The issue seems to be that phonegap is not copying the objective-c classes and headers into /platforms/ios/

```
william-macbook-pro:PhonegapPondMD william$ ls -l plugins/
total 8
-rw-r--r--   1 william  staff  296 Jan 16 10:32 ios.json
drwxr-xr-x  11 william  staff  374 Jan 16 10:30 org.apache.cordova.device

william-macbook-pro:PhonegapPondMD william$ ls -l platforms/ios/PondMD/Plugins/
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 william  staff  890 Jan 16 10:30 README

william-macbook-pro:PhonegapPondMD william$ phonegap -v
3.3.0-0.18.0
```

Comment: try to remove the plugin properly : "phonegap local plugin remove com.plugin.pluginid" and reinstall. I'm not sure that removing plugins and platforms cleans everything. Or try with a clean project.

Comment: @QuickFix. Just tried: "william-macbook-pro:PhonegapPondMD william$ phonegap local plugin remove org.apache.cordova.device; phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.device; phonegap build ios;".  Still get the build error.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem, and I solved It creating the project with uppercase in the first letter of project name. Yes, it seems incredible, but this was the solution.

Comment: This is the most ridiculous answer I've ever had to upvote!  This is definitely something that should be in the docs.

Comment: Another important detail: I think Cordova/Phonegap also has problems if the name of the project (and thus the name of the generated folder) has white spaces, at least in iOS.

Comment: this should be considered a bug to Phonegap

Comment: this is still an issue in Late November 2014

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by using the instructions here: [Cordova 3.2 ios add plugin "Which config.xml? Where is it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100248/cordova-3-2-ios-add-plugin-which-config-xml-where-is-it)

To summarize, I did the following steps:
1. Removed ios platform via: cordova platform remove ios
2. Re-installed the plugin
3. (Re-)Added the ios platform via: cordova platform add ios
4. Built the project again

After this, it built just fine.

Comment: Even more strange, it seems that all you need to do after adding any number of plugins, is remove and re-add your platforms. `cordova platform rm android ios && cordova platform add android ios && cordova build` works for me everytime I add a new plugin.

Comment: removing and re-adding ios platform results in lost of all the implementation done in the xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

When I added the plugin using `cordova plugin add` command, it puts the plugin code inside a **plugins** folder. 
When you inspect the plugin folder inside the ios platform, you would see the plugin is not available.

So I created a folder with the same name as the plugin name and copied the files from the plugin src/ directory into this. After this the project built correctly.

I also found it useful to open the native project in xcode to inspect the project closer.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the solution to copy the plugin files from ./plugins/.. to the ios platform plugin directory. Whoever needs it, here is a little helper for gulp.

(npm install gulp gulp-rename)

(gulpfile.js)

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
gulp.task("cp-plugins-ios", function(){
   gulp.src(["./plugins/*/src/ios/*"],{base: 'ios'}).pipe(rename(function(path){
      var myDir = path.dirname.replace("src/ios","");
      path.dirname = myDir;
   })).pipe(gulp.dest("./platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/"));
});
```